# Connection refused: connect in jhipster

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I am new to Jhipster. I have tried to run mvnw but request execution error of  Connection refused: connect is occurred.

```
2017-07-14 10:36:17.411  INFO 19864 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1500008777411, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2017-07-14 10:36:17.946  INFO 19864 --- [  restartedMain] com.lxisoft.diviso.DivisoApp             : Started DivisoApp in 27.953 seconds (JVM running for 29.457)
2017-07-14 10:36:17.961  INFO 19864 --- [  restartedMain] com.lxisoft.diviso.DivisoApp             :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'diviso' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:8080
        External:       http://192.168.43.43:8080
        Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
2017-07-14 10:36:17.978  INFO 19864 --- [  restartedMain] com.lxisoft.diviso.DivisoApp             :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Config Server:  Not found or not setup for this application
----------------------------------------------------------
2017-07-14 10:36:18.463  WARN 19864 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/diviso/dev/master": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2017-07-14 10:36:18.467  INFO 19864 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DIVISO/diviso:44489811627d5f65d0e44a2af1489c68: registering service...
2017-07-14 10:36:20.480 ERROR 19864 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
        at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.register(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:798)
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104)
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:88)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Look, this question doesn't have enough information to be answered precisely. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. These articles explain how to ask good questions - questions that can be answered.

Answer (score 6):

```
Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/diviso/dev/master": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

This warning message means that your application could not connect to its spring cloud config server: JHipster Registry.

In **dev** profile, this is just a **warning** that you can ignore as your application can run with local application properties in `sc/main/resources/config`.

In **prod** profile, this would be an **error** and your application would not start. The registry must be started before your app because this is where your app gets its application properties from and registers itself as an Eureka client.

So in dev, you can ignore this warning or if it annoys you, you can start a registry.

If your app is a monolith application and not a microservice application, you can opt out the discovery client question, it'll be simpler to deploy if you don't need horizontal scaling.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue happened with me, although I have already generated and modified my project before.

In case you are using MySql, go to phpMyAdmin page and type in your credentials. Worked for me.